# C++ strange behaviour with long doubles and optimized flag

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, optimization, floating-point

I'm developing a program in C++ with Visual Studio 2008. 
Recently i started to test my program in release mode, and i started to get some weird errors in relations to some calculations, which always return 0 instead of the correct value (that in debug mode were correctly calculated).

I have done some research and finally i identify (or at least i believe) what the problem is. If i disable the optimization flags (/Od) when i'm in release mode, the programs behaves well like usual in debug mode. But, because i really need the speed of this optimizations (at least with the O2 flag), i started to test a lot of things in order to get correct results while keep a good execution time. I set the floating point model to pf:strict option, but still get the same errors (my long doubles values still are 0).

Tracking this odd behaviour i get to this example code (which is inside a loop) (demand is a long double var):

```
long double demand = 0;
vector<int> someArray = getSomeArray();
for (int i = 0; i < someArray.size(); i++) {

    if (someCondition(someArray[i])) {

        int someId = getSomeId(someArray[i]);
        long double d = getSomeLongDouble(someArray[i]); <--- correctly setted!
        demand = demand + d; <---- d=0.018182000000000000 demand = 0
        someLogic(someId); <--- at this point, demand is still 0!!!!
    }

}
```

No matter what, demand is always 0, even when i insert a breakpoint and manually check that the value of the variable d is > 0. 
Please, i really need the boost of speed the optimization flags are giving, but i don't get how to keep this particular calculation correct...

Any help would be greatly appreciated :) And excuse my english!!

Comment: A common problem between debug and release mode happens when variables are not initialized properly. Are you sure you initialized `demand` before using it?

Comment: This would seem a no-brainer to post as an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org). The code you have here initializes an id that is never used, chains an additive assignment of a variable that is never declared, finally invoking a function that isn't posted. For all we know `demand` is an `int`, given the comment to the right of that assignment line. *Please* post real , compilable code that reproduces your issue.

Comment: I have edited my question. I really can't be more specific, as the logic is too complex and big to get it right here. But neverthless i think that the functions logic won't add anything useful, as they're behaving correctly and returning the correct results... it just the addition and assignment that don't work (demand don't get added the d value).